# How do I export a video from Openshot?

Tags: sound, video, codecs, openshot

I made a video with Openshot on Ubuntu 14.10. I want to export this video, along with the audio, for use on my computer and for uploading to YouTube. What format and codecs should I use?

Every time I try, the video is exported with no audio. The audio works fine in the Openshot preview. I have tried both libmp3lame and libvorbis, in various formats (I can't remember specifics). I have Ubuntu restricted extras installed. There were never any errors when I exported, just no audio and no explanation.

Comment: Right click on the video in 'tracks', go to properties, and make sure 'enable audio' is checked.

Comment: Right click on what video?

Comment: If you mean each video segment in the Openshot project, then yes, they all have audio enabled. Audio works fine in the preview panel.

Answer (score 1):

Get newer versions of `libmlt6` and `libmlt++3`.

```
cd $(mktemp -d)
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libmlt%2B%2B3_0.9.2%2Bgit20141027-1_amd64.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libmlt6_0.9.2%2Bgit20141027-1_amd64.deb
```

Then use

```
sudo dpkg -Oi *deb
```

to unpackage and install.

This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.10 when I had the same issue.